# intellij idea - cannot run "Tomcat" project on linux

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat8

When I configure Tomcat in "Run configuration"  in intellij, button "Tomcat" does not become active, as a result I can't run the project. I do not have any message about some errors. I went thorought many tutorials (even the most simple), but all was unsuccessful.
Here some screens

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are looking at the default setup. Not an actual configuration.

Click the green plus icon at the top of that list to open the 'Add New Configuration' menu, and select Tomcat>Local from there (you may need to click the 'X items more' option if it is not shown initially).
This will create a deployable config of tomcat based on the default setup you have shown here.